# How to install Impala on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, impala

I want to install [Impala](https://impala.apache.org/) on an Ubuntu instance. So far, none of the methods below didn't work.

How can I install a stable version of Impala in Ubuntu?

**Failed method nr. 1: apt-get**

First I tried to install binaries using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install impala
sudo apt-get install impala-server
sudo apt-get install impala-state-store
```

However, there are problems with the public key of Impala's repository:

```
Err:8 https://archive.cloudera.com/impala/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/impala bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.192.167 443]
Err:4 http://archive.cloudera.com/impala/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/impala lucid-impala1 InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 327574EE02A818DD
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://archive.cloudera.com/impala/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/impala bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by defau
lt.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.cloudera.com/impala/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/impala lucid-impala1 InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:
 NO_PUBKEY 327574EE02A818DD
E: The repository 'http://archive.cloudera.com/impala/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/impala lucid-impala1
 InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

**Failed method nr. 2: Building it**

I did `git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/impala.git`, then ran `bin/bootstrap_build.sh`.

However, the file [bootstrap_build.sh](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=impala.git;a=blob;f=bin/bootstrap_build.sh;h=82f1f37566327eb2001d41ae9194ddb04d552e51;hb=HEAD) references a non-existent shell script in the last line `./buildall.sh -notests -so`.

**Update 1:** When I run `sudo dpkg --install impala_2.11.0+cdh5.14.4+0-1.cdh5.14.4.p0.4~xenial-cdh5.14.4_amd64.deb` I get the following dependencies errors:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of impala:
 impala depends on bigtop-utils (>= 0.7); however:
  Package bigtop-utils is not installed.
 impala depends on hadoop; however:
  Package hadoop is not installed.
 impala depends on hadoop-hdfs; however:
  Package hadoop-hdfs is not installed.
 impala depends on hadoop-yarn; however:
  Package hadoop-yarn is not installed.
 impala depends on hadoop-mapreduce; however:
  Package hadoop-mapreduce is not installed.
 impala depends on hbase; however:
  Package hbase is not installed.
 impala depends on hive (>= 0.12.0+cdh5.1.0); however:
  Package hive is not installed.
 impala depends on zookeeper; however:
  Package zookeeper is not installed.
 impala depends on libhdfs0; however:
  Package libhdfs0 is not installed.
 impala depends on avro-libs; however:
  Package avro-libs is not installed.
 impala depends on parquet; however:
  Package parquet is not installed.
 impala depends on sentry (>= 1.3.0+cdh5.1.0); however:
  Package sentry is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package impala (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 impala
```

**Update 2:** Installing Hadoop according to [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-in-stand-alone-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04) did not fix the Hadoop dependency problems.

Comment: Are you planning on running Impala against HBase or Hive tables?  Do you plan on running it against HDFS?

Comment: I want to run Impala against a [standalone HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/standalone_dist.html) instance.

Comment: can you post your ubuntu version by this command `lsb-release -a` also post output of `sudo apt list --installed` which will be helpful to find the exact packages installed.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to install Impala if you grab packages that are bundled with a release since these are tied to a set of software versions.  Pick a CDH version (like cdh5.14.4 for example) then install the appropriate packages.  So looking at:

http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/pool/contrib/i/impala/

you can `wget` the packages and then run `dpkg install` to install them:

```
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/pool/contrib/i/impala/impala-catalog_2.11.0+cdh5.14.4+0-1.cdh5.14.4.p0.4~xenial-cdh5.14.4_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/pool/contrib/i/impala/impala-dbg_2.11.0+cdh5.14.4+0-1.cdh5.14.4.p0.4~xenial-cdh5.14.4_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/pool/contrib/i/impala/impala-server_2.11.0+cdh5.14.4+0-1.cdh5.14.4.p0.4~xenial-cdh5.14.4_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/pool/contrib/i/impala/impala-shell_2.11.0+cdh5.14.4+0-1.cdh5.14.4.p0.4~xenial-cdh5.14.4_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/pool/contrib/i/impala/impala-state-store_2.11.0+cdh5.14.4+0-1.cdh5.14.4.p0.4~xenial-cdh5.14.4_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/pool/contrib/i/impala/impala_2.11.0+cdh5.14.4+0-1.cdh5.14.4.p0.4~xenial-cdh5.14.4_amd64.deb

dpkg --install impal*.deb
```

To setup the Impala on Ubuntu16, do the following:

```
wget 'https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/cloudera.list'
mv cloudera.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudera.list
wget 'https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/archive.key'
apt-key add archive.key`
```

Then perform the original instructions:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install impala
sudo apt-get install impala-server
sudo apt-get install impala-state-store
```

#### References

- [Installing the Latest CDH 5 Release - On Ubuntu or Debian Systems](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html#concept_gp2_q32_24)
- [Installing the Latest CDH 5 Release - Step 2: Optionally Add a Repository Key](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html#topic_4_4_2)

Comment: Thanks. How do I install all the required dependencies automatically (see update 1 in my question)?

Comment: updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use github repo but stable branch i.e. 2.x

And while installing from dpkg won't install all dependencies, you have two options:

1. install all dependencies from error

   I have used the script / heredoc below to generate a command. It can be used with other errors by changing the error messages in the heredoc.
2. use `apt-get install ./impala_2.11.0+cdh5.14.4+0-1.cdh5.14.4.p0.4~xenial-cdh5.14.4_amd64.deb`

   This is the easier method as everything is taken care of.

```
$ echo "sudo apt-get install " `grep "Package" << Devidas | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\r\n' ' ' ; echo ' '
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of impala:
 impala depends on bigtop-utils (>= 0.7); however:
  Package bigtop-utils is not installed.
 impala depends on hadoop; however:
  Package hadoop is not installed.
 impala depends on hadoop-hdfs; however:
  Package hadoop-hdfs is not installed.
 impala depends on hadoop-yarn; however:
  Package hadoop-yarn is not installed.
 impala depends on hadoop-mapreduce; however:
  Package hadoop-mapreduce is not installed.
 impala depends on hbase; however:
  Package hbase is not installed.
 impala depends on hive (>= 0.12.0+cdh5.1.0); however:
  Package hive is not installed.
 impala depends on zookeeper; however:
  Package zookeeper is not installed.
 impala depends on libhdfs0; however:
  Package libhdfs0 is not installed.
 impala depends on avro-libs; however:
  Package avro-libs is not installed.
 impala depends on parquet; however:
  Package parquet is not installed.
 impala depends on sentry (>= 1.3.0+cdh5.1.0); however:
  Package sentry is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package impala (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 impala
Devidas`
```

This should result in something like:

```
sudo apt-get install bigtop-utils hadoop hadoop-hdfs hadoop-yarn hadoop-mapreduce \
    hbase hive zookeeper libhdfs0 avro-libs parquet sentry
```