# Installing Impala

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala

I've installed hadoop and hive on my ubuntu 18.1....but I found difficulty in installing Impala
Is there a link to install imapala in ubuntu without cloudera manager.

Couldn't able to install with official link since it appears to need large memory

I've tried this one...
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/impala/ubuntu/precise/amd64/impala/cloudera.list

but its a bit old..

and this one
[How to install Impala on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502493/how-to-install-impala-on-ubuntu)

but it's not working for me since it apparently comes with its own hadoop and hive folders..

Comment: Hi there, you tagged your question with [tag:cloudera] and you mention that you tried to download sources from cloudera, but you also mention that you don't want to use the cloudera manager. That's a bit confusing. What exactly is your setup? Are you using the cloudera manager or are you not using the cloudera manager? It would be quite easy if you were using it, especially because you wouldn't need to think too much about whether the versions of your different tools can work together, but if you insist you could check out the [impala](https://impala.apache.org/downloads.html) apache project.

Comment: If your second paragraph means that your disk space is insufficient to even download Impala you should think about increasing the size of your server, virtual machine or whatever it is where you are trying to install this exactly - such a small system won't be able to help you get any meaningful work done with these tools if you can't store any data anywhere.